# "%22" added to URL paths in production build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker, server-side-rendering, workbox

I'm having some trouble figuring out what's going wrong in our production build. Sometimes, loading up a page works perfects. Othertimes, everything breaks, and the request URLs go from

example.com/static/js/2017.4d0339ef.chunk.js

TO

example.com/%22/static/js/2017.4d0339ef.chunk.js/%22

The page can consistently be broken by triggering a hard refresh (ctrl+shift+r), but sometimes the bad request URLs are used on the first load anyhow.

This a react app, uses server-side rendering, serviceWorkers, workbox, webpack.

It seems like workbox might be encoding the paths as a string and passing them out in JS form, and somewhere in the build process our index file is requesting those paths (hence the %22 insertion).

If anyone has encountered something like this before, or might be able to provide some direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here are some images of the issue:

**Page**

[image of the broken page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLC3O.png)

**Elements Tab**

[elements tab, where all the html variables are escaped with \"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPPXq.jpg)

[elements tab, additional image of items inside of the body tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDYBA.png)

**Network Tab**

[network tab, where all calls have been converted to requesting %22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13gVL.png)

Heres the GenerateSW area from webpack, if that's helpful

```
isEnvProduction &&
    new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
      clientsClaim: true,
      exclude: [
        /assets-icons-.+-js/,
        /\.map$/,
        /asset-manifest\.json$/,
        /hot-update\.(js|json)$/,
      ],
      navigateFallback: paths.publicUrlOrPath + "index.html",
      navigateFallbackDenylist: [
        // Exclude URLs starting with /_, as they're likely an API call
        new RegExp("^/_"),
        // Exclude any URLs whose last part seems to be a file extension
        // as they're likely a resource and not a SPA route.
        // URLs containing a "?" character won't be blacklisted as they're likely
        // a route with query params (e.g. auth callbacks).
        new RegExp("/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$"),
      ],
    }),
```

And the manifest plugin in webpack

```
new ManifestPlugin({
    fileName: "asset-manifest.json",
    publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
    generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
      const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
        manifest[file.name] = file.path;
        return manifest;
      }, seed);
      const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(
        (fileName) => !fileName.endsWith(".map")
      );

      return {
        files: manifestFiles,
        entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
      };
    },
  }),
```

UPDATE: Just noticed that the things that are supposed to be in  are being placed into the body. Given ssr takes the style scripts it finds and replaces the  tag inside the

If there is no head on the document then there should be no link, meta, or style tags because there would be no  tag to replace. Still not sure what the core issue is here, but that seems to be a helpful clue

[network tab, raw HTML from first call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXYD0.png)

*Note: In the network tab, the first call correctly places the head items where they belong (in the head), but still have an abundance of \n and "\"data\"" things, which is slightly different from the elements tab, where all the items that should be in the head, are now in the body*

*link to live site where the problem is occurring*
https://stage.cryptohedgehog.io/

**SOLVED:**
Couple items here. First off, we were referencing req.url on both the client and the server, but req.url gets mutated by babel on the client, so we switched that variable name to req.originalUrl

Secondly, our server saves json data, which is stringify’d before being sent to redis. We also convert the html into a buffer stream on the client, so we can send the data in pieces instead of as one big chunk.

So we were converting the HTML into a string for storage on redis, using the Buffer.toString() method, and also applying the json.stringify method on the buffer, which was screwing up the cached result in redis.

Yowza what a loop.

Comment: %20 is an encoded space - wonder if there's any kind of space in your paths anywhere.

Comment: `%22` is encoded `"` (quote sign). It seems you have two, one at the beginning and one at the end of the relative URL. Maybe you are using quotes somewhere where they shouldn't be?

Comment: @Squiggs. But %22 is a quote. So if the request path is create via something like var path = `https://example.com/${chunk}`, instead of creating "https://example.com/static/chuckpath.js" it's creating "https://example.com/%22static/chuckpath.js%22"

Comment: @Sulthan That was my thought too, but the weird part is that it loads just fine sometimes. We thought it might have to do with JSON.stringify, but we don't appear to be doing that to any of the pathnames...and the %22 %22 wrapper is added to EVERY call when it breaks (not just one or two)

Comment: Added the ManifestPlugin and GenerateSW plugin from webpack, incase that's helpful

Comment: What type of urls are you trying to match with `new RegExp("^/_")`?   What would that match?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat /__webpack_hmr (it's for hot module reloading), or if we were serving the api on the same stack we could put the api on /_api

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Sorry, there is a slash before webpack_hmr, it just got cut off from my copy/paste. But the slash doesn't need to be escaped because it's a RegExp object (At least, I'm 95% sure it doesn't need to be escaped)

Comment: Sure seems like a JSNO issue somewhere.  On the broken page image there's a string of `"\n\n\n\n\n\n`, no way to trace where that value comes from?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I just added an image of the Elements tab of the broken page image. The chain of \n's come from the links / scripts / meta tags in the header, but I can't identify why they're like that yet

Comment: Seems like it must be in your webpack config somehwere or one of the plugins.  You say they're in your production build using SSR, can you tell if they're in the raw html which should be the first thing in the network tab?  Can you try disabling SSR?  Are you using a service worker and if so could you try disabling it and deleting everything in your appication tab in chrome dev tools?  Does it happen always/sometimes/never when you try an incognito window or different browser?  Does it not happen when running locally?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I added some details on the RAW html above, along with a link to the live site at the bottom, where the problem is happening. It sometimes happens in incognito, and we've been testing it on Brave, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, with similar results across the board. ctrl+shift+r usually triggers it. Working on your other questions now :)
Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: Sounds like you found the problem, good to hear!